# JPA repository custom UPDATE query not being called

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have written a custom UPDATE query for one of entities in the corresponding JPA repository. The reason for not using the standard `save()` method is that the entity has relations with some other entities who's corresponding tables are not editable. So, the `save()` method fails as it tries to update all the columns of the table.
But, now, instead of running the custom update query, which only sets 3 of the 54 columns, JPA executes the standard update query, as if it would have called the `save()` method.

I have my SQL logs on. Weirdly, I have another entity (without any relations) for which I have wrote a custom UPDATE query in its corresponding repository. This works perfectly fine as per the SQL logs. Just for the entity in question the standard update query is logged.

Here's some pseudo code for better understanding
ProblematicEntity:

```
@Table("Problem")
@Entity
@Data
public class ProblematicEntity{
    @Id
    @Column("id")
    private Long id;

    @Column("last_update_date")
    private LocalDate lastUpdateDate;

    @Column("last_update_user_id")
    private String lastUpdateUserId;

    @Column("name")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany("Uneditable_table")
    private List<NoEditEntity> noEditEntitites;

    ...(54 columns)
}
```

ProblematicRepository:

```
public interface ProblematicRepository extends JPARepository<ProblematicEntity, Long> {

    @Modifying(clearAutomatically = true)
    @Query("update ProblematicEntity pe set pe.name = :name, pe.lastModifiedDate = :today"+
        ", pe.lastModifiedUserId = :userId where sr.id = :id")
    int updateName(@Param("id") Long id, @Param("name") String name
        , @Param("today") LocalDate today, @Param("userId") String userId);

}
```

ProblematicService:

```
@Service
public class ProblematicServiceImpl implements ProblematicService {

    @Autowired
    ProblematicRepository repo;

    @Override
    @MyAppTransaction
    public Long updateName(Long id, String name, LocalDate today, String userId){
        return new Long(repo.updateName(id, name, today, userId));
    }
}
```

Now as per expectation, once this code is executed the logs should be something like this:

```
update SCHEMA.PROBLEM set NAME=?, LAST_MODIFIED_DATE=?, LAST_MODIFIED_USER_ID=? where ID=?
```

But instead the actual SQL logs are as:

```
update SCHEMA.PROBLEM set NAME=?, LAST_MODIFIED_DATE=?, LAST_MODIFIED_USER_ID=?
, NO_EDIT_ID_1=?, NO_EDIT_ID_2=?
, ....(All 54 columns)
where ID=?
```

Comment: What is @MyAppTransaction? You should use @Transactional with a configured transaction manager

Comment: @dimirsen I have multiple transaction managers configured in my project. So this is a custom annotation representing one of them

Comment: What are the values for the real update? Do the other fields have NOT NULL ?

Comment: @jordiburgos There is no other "NOt Null" constraint for fields other than the ID. Well, since, this is a update query it doesn't matter, does it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because once you load an entity from JPA it is attached to the `EntityManager` and when changed will automatically be flushed at some time before the transaction commits.

To avoid this detach the entities in question.
See [`EntityManager.detach`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#detach-java.lang.Object-)